# android studio arctic fox bug (classes is encrypted) in flutter or normal android project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, render, android-studio-arctic-fox

I've updated my android studio to arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 3 and i faced below errors

- App runs normally but some classes that i written before are encrypted but when i deleted my project and redownload it, its working normally.
- Another existing bugs in any library classes, i cannot view them at all, examples listed below

**Flutter Slider Class**
[image]

**Flutter Tab Controller Class**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of the new version of android studio, preferably to use it but to compile with an external terminal or try to use vscode at home the two solutions works and do not forget to version your code with Git for possible reset.